# LINQ - Set element in Dictionary to empty where DateTime value is oldest

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have a `Dictionary<string, XMLMessage>` where XMLMessage is a struct:

```
    private struct XMLMessage
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeRead { get; set; }
    }
```

I will use the Dictionary similar to this:

```
storedMessages["1X"] = new XMLMessage() { Message = "<XML>1X</XML>", TimeRead = DateTime.Now };
storedMessages["1Y"] = new XMLMessage() { Message = "<XML>1Y</XML>", TimeRead = DateTime.Now };
```

There will be a gap in seconds between the the dictionary object assigning a value hence the DateTime object.

At some point I need to keep the keys in the Dictionary but the oldest value to be set to empty.

I have tried this but don't seem to have got it quite right.

```
storedMessages.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("1")).OrderBy(s => s.Value.TimeRead).Skip(1)
```

Thanks

**UPDATE: I think I can do something like this but wanted to get your opinions**

```
var j = storedMessages.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("1")).OrderByDescending(s => s.Value.TimeRead).First().Key;
storedMessages[j] = new XMLMessage();
```

Comment: Which item is it selecting?  That looks workable to me...

Comment: Have you considered using SortedDictionary ? Are incoming messages, to be added to the storedMessages Dictionary, always sequential in time : i.e., you'll never want to add a message with a DateTime earlier than any preceding DateTime already added to the Dictionary ?
If the incoming messages are sequential, then I think using a SortedDictionary with a simply incremented counter as a key means you will always have the "oldest entry" at beginning of the list; as you set the DateTime value of that entry to empty, you then advance a counter variable, so you have a pointer to the oldest entry.

Comment: @BillW: Any reason for not putting that as an answer?

Comment: @JSkeet Because I had not personally tested the idea in code ... and reading "C# in Depth" has convinced me I am an ignoramus (for which I am very thankful !) :) best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your updated version looks okay - although I'd say you'd be better off storing a list in time order as well as the dictionary, to make life easier.

I would *strongly* discourage you from using mutable structs though. Either use a class, or change the struct to be immutable.

Example of making it a class:

```
private class XmlMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeRead { get; set; }
}
```

Example of making it an immutable struct:

```
private struct XmlMessage
{
    private readonly string message;
    private readonly DateTime timeRead;

    public string Message { get { return message; } }
    public DateTime TimeRead { get { return timeRead; } }

    public XmlMessage(string message, DateTime timeRead)
    {
        this.message = message;
        this.timeRead = timeRead;
    }
}
```

Of course you could make it an immutable class instead...

Comment: I'm unsure on both counts - could you explain more or provide an example